Folium map not displayed in Safari
I have created a map with Folium in Python. It is displayed in Chrome. But Safari just shows the page in blank and the map is not displayed. The problem persists after removing markers and other elements with pop ups.
I sent the file via whastapp and email to lot of Safari users with Iphone. It is always displayed the page in blank.
I am not an expert in html neither CSS or JavaScript.
This is the most simple version of the script in Python:
z = folium.Map()

z.save("Map with nothing.html")

This is the html file created:
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
        <script>
            L_NO_TOUCH = false;
            L_DISABLE_3D = false;
        </script>
    
    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/python-visualization/folium/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.min.css"/>
    
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                #map_c1ca8abfae87cf05439dfa4dfd5b4c96 {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100.0%;
                    height: 100.0%;
                    left: 0.0%;
                    top: 0.0%;
                }
                .leaflet-container { font-size: 1rem; }
            </style>
        
</head>
<body>
    
            <div class="folium-map" id="map_c1ca8abfae87cf05439dfa4dfd5b4c96" ></div>
        
</body>
<script> 
    
            var map_c1ca8abfae87cf05439dfa4dfd5b4c96 = L.map(
                "map_c1ca8abfae87cf05439dfa4dfd5b4c96",
                {
                    center: [0.0, 0.0],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 1,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );

            var tile_layer_2223daa336910949acb89349d7b8a0c8 = L.tileLayer(
                "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                {"attribution": "\u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e contributors", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 19, "maxZoom": 19, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
            );
        
    
            tile_layer_2223daa336910949acb89349d7b8a0c8.addTo(map_c1ca8abfae87cf05439dfa4dfd5b4c96);
        
</script>
</html> 

